# android string how to put & character

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In theory simple thing but I can't find asnwer...

in my xml android code I want to have:

Q&A .txt

And instead of & character eclipse treats that as entity reference. Thus how to put & as normal string char?

Comment: http://www.dvteclipse.com/documentation/svlinter/How_to_use_special_characters_in_XML.3F.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entity reference for ampersand is

```
&amp;
```

So in XML:

```
Q&amp;A.txt
```

Comment: I've found now even a bit more: Here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters we have the list of all Unicodes chars. Thus I could also use &#38;